# Drupal Pop-Up Image on page load

Tags: updating, javascript

With simple css and javascript code i have created image pop-up which loads automatically after page load, i want to load the pop-up between two specific days (example from date and to date)
please help me with this, is there any module in drupal

Comment: Paste you css & js code for popup.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using the [Popup On Load](https://www.drupal.org/project/popup_onload) module.

> The module allows to display a popup once after a certain delay on a page load. This fills a gap in popup modules family (Popups, Popup), which are designed to show popups only after a click on an HTML element, or to implement a complex behavior like modal dialog forms.
>
> If you want to just display a popup after a page load, the Popup On Load module possibly fits your needs

The following are one of the module's main features. See project page for more.

- Create an action for popup display, which can be easily integrated
  into Rules system.
- Create a default rules set for popup display.